# Interesting phenomena with sum of all naturals

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Discovered something interesting while I was playing around.

Let $c$ be the sum of all naturals, i.e. $c = 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + \ldots$

Then $3c = 3 + 6 + 9 + 12 + \ldots$

It appears that every term in $3c$ is equal to the sum of three immediately following terms in $c$. e.g.

$$3 = 0 + 1 + 2$$
$$6 = 1 + 2 + 3$$
$$9 = 2 + 3 + 4$$
etc. So basically $$3c = (c_0 + c_1 + c_2) + (c_1 + c_2 + c_3) + (c_2 + c_3 + c_4) + \ldots $$
where $c_i$ is the $i$th term of $c$. Why is this? It looks related to the partial sums of $c$, e.g. 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, etc. Probably missing something obvious, but that's the way it goes.

Thanks for any help in figuring this out.

Comment: Well, you are manipulating a series that doesn't exist in the normal sense.

Comment: How do you define "the sum of all naturals" ?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I know that it diverges, but the phenomena is there even if you only sum up to $n$.

Comment: Clearly $3n=(n-1)+n+(n+1)$,hence the pattern.

Comment: Damn. So I was missing something obvious. Cheers, kingW3.

Comment: @InstantRamen It's still not useful to think of it as a series rather than merely  sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that $3n=(n-1)+n+(n+1)$ from that you can write each term as sum of $3$ consecutive terms.